# extracting depth image from .bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to extract depth image from .bag file just like [the tutorial](http://answers.ros.org/question/9652/extracting-images-from-rosbag/).
But when I run `$ roslaunch export.launch` , the error occurred as below:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    extract (image_view/extract_images)
    rosbag (rosbag/play)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rosbag-1]: started with pid [9394]
process[extract-2]: started with pid [9405]
[ INFO] [1413444044.771603283]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000

 [ERROR] [1413444046.270973202]: Client [/extract] wants topic /camera/depth/disparity to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [stereo_msgs/DisparityImage/04a177815f75271039fa21f16acad8c9]. Dropping connection.
```

pls help me to resolve it.Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195099/extracting-depth-image-from-.bag-file/) by [hffgodspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/14891/hffgodspeed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That script you are running is designed for color images not depth images. You'll need to modify it a little bit to support the different data type.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hffgodspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/14891/hffgodspeed/) on 2014-10-20**:
Could you please tell me how to modify it? Thank you.